# OpenAPI cannot handle multiple controller methods with same path

Tags: spring-boot, openapi

I have Controller with multiple GET endpoints having same path. The only difference is the @RequestParam passed into the method.

This is perfectly valid and common scenario in APIs. Spring / Java does not complain about it, nor does OpenAPI; however, openApi interprets this incorrectly in addition to some other issues like described below with the Custom-Authentication parameter. Swagger 2 was handling this fine with the use of one of its @ApiParameter annotations.

Given that neither Spring, nor Java, nor Swagger 2, nor OpenAPI error out because of this, this seam to be a quite limitation of OpenAPI and it looks like a bug.

Here is my example:

```java
    @GetMapping(path = "", params = {"id"}, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    @Operation(
        operationId = "getUsersById",
        summary = "Returns all users records with the same id.",
        description = "Retrieves users from persistence storage by given id.",
        tags = {"UserController"},
        parameters = {
            @Parameter(in = ParameterIn.HEADER,
                name = "Custom-Authorization",
                description = "Jwt Bearer Token",
                example = "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzU...",
                required = true,
                schema = @Schema(type = "string"))
        },
        responses = {
            @ApiResponse(
                responseCode = "200",
                description = "Users Json array.",
                content = @Content(array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = UserResponse.class)))),
            @ApiResponse(
                responseCode = "404",
                description = "User(s) with provided id could not be found.",
                content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ResponseEntity.class))) 
        })
    public List<UserResponse> getUsersById(
        @Parameter(name = "id", example = "1234567", required = true)
        @RequestParam String id) throws MyException {

        ...
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "", params = {"lastName"}, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    @Operation(hidden = true,
        operationId = "getUserByLastName",
        summary = "Returns all user records with the same last name.",
        description = "Retrieves users from persistence storage by given last name.",
        tags = {"UserController"},
//        parameters = {
//            @Parameter(in = ParameterIn.HEADER,
//                name = "Custom-Authorization",
//                description = "Jwt Bearer Token",
//                example = "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzU...",
//                required = true,
//                schema = @Schema(type = "string"))
//        },
        responses = {
            @ApiResponse(
                responseCode = "200",
                description = "Users Json array.",
                content = @Content(array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = UserResponse.class)))),
            @ApiResponse(
                responseCode = "404",
                description = "Users with provided last name could not be found.",
                content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ResponseEntity.class))) 
        })
    public List<UserResponse> getUserLastName(
        @Parameter(name = "lastName", example = "Tester", required = true)
        @RequestParam String lastName) throws MyException {
        
        ...
    }
```

This issue springdoc/springdoc-openapi#580 suggests using @Hidden, or hidden on others endpoint and therefore showing only one of them which is what I did above; however, this is obviously incorrect and not a good solution.

The other issue is that I cannot provide parameter for my Custom-Authorization header, so I had to comment it in the hidden endpoints; otherwise, I get error like "duplicate parameter" or something along the way.

Comment: i am facing the same problem as you. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No unfortunately.  OpenApi feels like step backward tbh Ava their team at GitHub simply ignores the question